# Supremum infinum notation

Tags: metric-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

I came across the following question: Let $\Omega$ denote the set of closed subsets of $[0,1]$. Show that $\rho : \Omega \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$\rho(A,B) := \max\left\{\sup_{x\in A}\inf_{y \in B}\vert x - y \vert, \sup_{y \in B}\inf_{x \in A}\vert x - y \vert\right\}.$$
I just want to know what this is supposed to mean. How can you take the infinum of $\vert x - y \vert$ over $y \in B$ before choosing an $x \in A$? And it makes no sense to take the supremum and infinum at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially you just read it from left to right as
$$
\sup_{x\in A}\left(\inf_{y\in B}|x-y|\right).
$$
In other words, to compute $\sup_{x\in A}\inf_{y\in B}|x-y|$, we first find
$$
\alpha_x:=\inf_{y\in B}|x-y|
$$
for each $x\in A$ and then take $\sup_{x\in A}\alpha_x$.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I assume we want to exclude the empty set?

Comment: @EthanAlwaise Correct. Both $A$ and $B$ should be nonempty unless there is some notion of the infimum/supremum of the empty set in $[0,1]$.